# sum multiple variables in one constraint with choco

Tags: java, choco

I am using choco to solve a CSP , and one of my constraints is that the sum of all my 5 variables is less than 10 . for a sum of two variables we can use the function arithm

```
model.arithm(x1,"+",x2,"<",10).post();
```

but this method can't accept more variables 
so is there a way add this constraint ?

Comment: In answer to OP: doesn't look like it. You may have to do this outside of pure Choco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the [sum](http://www.choco-solver.org/apidocs/org/chocosolver/solver/constraints/IIntConstraintFactory.html#sum-org.chocosolver.solver.variables.IntVar:A-java.lang.String-int-) constraint not work for you?

```
model.sum(new IntVar[]{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}, "<", 10).post()
```